# How to set a class property in a controller's function and and use it in the other function?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set a class property in a function and use its value in the other function in the same class. But it gives me null instead!

```
class FormController{     
  private $formId;

   public function createForm(Request $request)
   {
       $formId = DB::table('forms')->insertGetId([
            'formlink' => $formLink,
            'created_at' => now(),
            'userid' => Session::get('id')
        ]);
        $this->formId=$formId;

    }
    public function getFormId(){
        return $this->formId;// it returns null
}
```

my routes:

```
 Route::get('/clientarea/form/create',[FormController::class,'createForm']);
```

then

```
Route::post('/clientarea/form/get',[FormController::class,'getFormId']);
```

Comment: I think in each route it's creating a new instance of FormController class then it is returning null in second function call

Comment: there is no such persistence like what you are trying to do which would be completely dependent on a single instance of a class holding a member variable ... you would need to pass that id back via a response so the next request could use it, or persist that value some how, perhaps the session

Answer (score 0):

can you dump the value of DB query. it is possible that it is null. since the question is use in another function. the way you do it is good. to check that it is working. please assign a default value to $formId
the code should be like this

```
class FormController{
```

private $formId="test";

public function createForm(Request $request)
{

```
    $this->formId='test edit';

}
public function getFormId(){
    return $this->formId;// it returns null
}
```

}

pls try to dump the value of formId if it gets updated